# How is this behaviour of C explained?

Tags: c, recursion, decrement

so I was playing around with recursion in C and I am not sure why is this happening:
**code A**

```
int foo(int x)
{
 if (x==0) return 0;
 else return foo(--x)+x;
}

int main() { printf("%d\n", foo(10));
```

**code B**

```
int foo(int x)
{
 if (x==0) return 0;
 else return foo(x--)+x;
}

int main() { printf("%d\n", foo(10));
```

Code A prints 45 instead of 55 and I figured that out. It is because the recursive call gets unwounded this way: `9+8+7+...+0 = 45`

Code B on the other hand gets stuck and never returns to the prompt!! i have to `ctrl+c` it. Why does it get stuck? Is it because it never decrements past 10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because in snippet B x gets decremented *after* the recursive call so the function is always called with foo(10)

**EDIT:**
As James McNellis pointed out in its comment x gets decremented before calling the function but its original value is used in the call instead of the decremented one.
Basically the expression x-- is evaluated before foo(x--) but its value is actually x, therefore the function is called with x = 10

Comment: This is technically incorrect:  the new, decremented value of `x` is stored _before_ the recursive call to `foo` because there is a sequence point between the evaluation of `x--` and the call of the function.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis are you saying that, altough x gets decremented before the function is called, the value used for calling foo is the one it had originally?

Comment: Yes.  There are two different issues:  the value of the expression `x--`, and when the storing of the new value takes place.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Thank you, I've just edited my answer to explain this

Comment: i am confused, if the value of x is stored before recursive call, then why isn't it used in the recursive call?

Comment: @infinitloop: It is stored because all the arguments of a function are evaluated before calling that function, so x gets decremented. But you are calling the function with the value of x--, which is actually x.

Answer (score 2):

Post-decrement `(x--)` waits for the function call to return before executing. So your stack would look like:

```
foo(10)
foo(10)
foo(10)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of the expression `x--` is the current value of `x`, before the stored value is decremented.  So, in calling `foo(x--)`, the value of the argument to `foo` is always the same as its current value, yielding infinite recursion.

---

Note, however, that the behavior of both programs is potentially undefined, and depends on the  order of evaluation of the subexpressions of `foo(x--) + x` and `foo(--x) + x`.  Let's consider the first program, which contains the expression

```
foo(--x) + x
```

If the subexpressions are evaluated in the following (valid!) order, the program has undefined behavior:

1. `x` is read to compute the value of the `x` as the right-hand side operand of `+`,
2. `x` is read to compute the value of the `x` as an operand of `--`,
3. `x` is written to store the new value of `x` after it is decremented
4. `foo` is called

The only sequence point here is between steps 3 and 4:  after the argument expression is evaluated, before the function is called.  Because `x` is read twice (in [1] and [2]) and written once (in [3]) and because one of the reads (in [1]) is not for the purpose of computing the new value to be stored, the behavior is undefined.

Evaluation order is *unspecified*, but if this evaluation order is the order that is used, the program has undefined behavior.

The same reasoning applies equally to the second program.

It would be best to use `x - 1` as the argument to `foo`, as this expression does not modify the value of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it never decrements at all.

```
    else return foo(x--)+x;
```

In the line where you call your function, you use a postdecrement, which means the value 10 is first passed to your next function and after that, it is decremented - which never happens since no function ever returns

Answer (score 0):

calling

```
foo(--x)
```

calls the function with the already decremented value, while

```
foo(x--)
```

always calls it with the original value (i. e. 10), so it never gets even close to zero, that's why.